# Qt / C++ max path length

Tags: c++, qt, path, max

I need to allocate space for a file name (including path) in C++ using Qt.  I'm want to ensure I allocate enough space, but cannot find where the max path length is defined.

I found lots of postings to _MAX_PATH MAX_PATH PATH_MAX, etc...but lots of follow-up postings saying these are wrong/unreliable/implementation specific/etc.

Since I'm building for Linux, is there a value I can reference anywhere?

---

More info:  here is code showing how and why I am converting:

```
struct stat existing_fileinfo, new_fileinfo;  // Structs to get file info
int existingFileStat = fstat(m_securityLogFile->handle(),&existing_fileinfo);
char filename_asterisk_securitylog[1024];  // Max path length?
QByteArray filename_asterisk_securitylog_array(programSettings->asterisk_securitylog().toLatin1().data());
memcpy(filename_asterisk_securitylog,filename_asterisk_securitylog_array,filename_asterisk_securitylog_array.size());
int newFileStat = stat(filename_asterisk_securitylog, &new_fileinfo);
```

Comment: Can you use `std::string`, or are you worried your path might hit some limit in the string implementation?

Comment: Where are you reading this path from? Is there some reason you can't use something like QString or QByteArray/QBuffer to let the memory management happen automatically?

Comment: I am sending the path to the sys/stat function which requires const * char as a type...so I need to convert it first.  See above.

Comment: Then you just do `stat(theStringWithThePath.c_str(), &new_fileinfo);`